# How to remove suggestions from Firefox's address bar history

Tags: firefox, history, address-bar

When typing a URL in Firefox's address bar, the suggestions tend to be noisy and polluted with a lot of unwanted entries, some from years ago and some that are just no longer needed.

I tried going into `Tools > Settings > Privacy and Security`, and clicking *Manage Data* to clear the data for some sites that I no longer want to show up here, but it seems this option doesn't affect address bar suggestions at all.

How can I actually prevent these unwanted address bar suggestions from showing up again?

Comment: If Firefox is similar to Chrome, there should be an internal page for the omnibox, similar to `chrome://omnibox/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete selected address bar suggestions

It seems that at least as of 2022, the formerly Chrome-exclusive shortcut of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> now works on Firefox to remove individual search suggestions, as [documented here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-address-bar-suggestions). Simply use the arrow keys to rollover the suggestion you no longer want to see, and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> to delete it.

This was enough for me to get rid of outdated `localhost` and similar entries that I no longer wanted clogging up my site suggestions.

---

### Delete *all* address bar suggestions

If you want to go further and remove *all* address bar suggestions for every site you've ever visited:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> to bring up Clear History
2. Change *Time range to clear* to `Everything`
3. Uncheck all checkboxes apart from `Browsing and download history`
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to clear all your suggestions (this may take a few seconds)

More detailed instructions can be found at the [documentation here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-address-bar-suggestions).

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks for catching that typo, although it wasn't really worth a downvote and could just as easily have been edited.

Comment: I didn't downvote.. someone else did. And the typo was easily mistaken for various troll efforts to have people reboot their computer. Anyway, thanks for editing.

Comment: At least in Firefox 117 I currently have a buggy behavior where I can delete *some* entries from the suggestions. Shift+Del works for most of the suggestions, but some just can't be deleted. Aparently this happens when entries are bookmarked, but in my case this is definitely not the case. Even using the deletion button via the three-dots-menu doesn't work. Anyone got ideas if this is a known bug?